# R - How to reduce the number of Bars in a Barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Hi there my problem is the following:

I need to barplot the number of breakdowns on the y by the service life on the x.

This should be easy but I can't find an option to sum up the service life correct, so I just get for each service time one bar.

The solution should look like the picture below.

[my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBmhq.png)

[diagram (solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m3ZZ.png)

Comment: That's not a bar plot, that's a histogram! `hist(data$Lifetime)`. See `?hist` you can "recommend" a number of bars, e.g., `hist(data$Lifetime, breaks = 10)` (or use a wide variety of other options).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for [histogram](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html) rather than barplot. Run something like this:

```
hist(X20S_IngInf_Daten_Abschlussprojekt_2$Lifetime,
     main = "",
     xlab = "Service life (operating hours to breakdown)",
     ylab = "Number of reported breakdowns",
     breaks = 14,
     col = "steelblue")
```

With `hist()` you can specify the number of `breaks`, axis texts (`main`, `xlab`, `ylab`), color (`col`) of the bars and many more. See more information in the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html).

**Example:**

```
hist(rnorm(1000, mean = 10000, sd = 1000),
     main = "",
     xlab = "Service life (operating hours to breakdown)",
     ylab = "Number of reported breakdowns",
     breaks = 14,
     col = "steelblue")
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: ok great thanks Petr, that helps but I got another Problem with hist()... running the code brings the error 'x must be numeric' in the console. Would be awesome if you can help me twice! thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @PaulHenke, it's quite difficult to say when I don't have your data, but probably you could try to convert the column to numeric as follows: `hist(as.numeric(X20S_IngInf_Daten_Abschlussprojekt_2$Lifetime))`? Let me know if that works.

Comment: Hi @PetrKajzar, yeah it works! thank you so much!! :)

Comment: @PaulHenke Great, I'm glad it works for you! And feel free to [mark this question as resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).